# Screen Time keeps turning off by itself

Tags: ipad, screen-time

I bought two iPads for my daughters as the school requested. Obviously, I set up screen time and content limits.

However, they keep resetting, screen time turns off, all the content restrictions are removed, app time limits are ignored, everything becomes available. Out of the blue, no action on anyone's part (except for the kids using their iPads normally).

I saw it happen in front of me. Apps suddenly un-grayed themselves and became available.

What caused this? Did I do something wrong?

I created Apple IDs under my family for both girls. Set up the iPads with their account. Entered into screen time, created a password, added the restrictions. It worked initially.

I upgraded to latest iOS. Problem happened again.

Comment: From your description, you've done all the necessary steps to set it up properly, but the key for me is that you watched, in real time that it "un-greyed themselves." You should open a case with Apple Support in this instance.  as it sounds like a bug.

Comment: Or they're enrolled in something from the school, that's enforcing a different set of parameters.

Comment: No enrollment to school happened yet.